# Run 2 queries together but execute separately

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have 2 separate queries which i need to run together, but execute separately, and i was wondering what would be the best practice to do this.

I have a query that dynamically prints out restaurants each and every time one is added in the admin page, and i have a query that works out if the restaurant is open or closed. I thought this would be simple by executing the 2 separate queries then saving the opening times echo into a variable and putting this variable inside the loop, however, that does not seem to be working. By not working I mean the wrong id is being called as the opening hrs query is before the dynamic print out query, and when it is after the query works the plan, but then my echo/print out variable does not work. I am struck and have no idea how to move forward.

**Opening hr query**

```
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM Opening_hrs 
  WHERE Restaurant_ID='$rest_id' AND Day_of_week = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%w')
  AND CURTIME() BETWEEN Open_time AND Closing_time");

$run_qu = $dbc->query($query);

if($run_qu->num_rows>0){
    while($row_qu=$run_qu->fetch_assoc()){
        $message= "open" .$row_qu["Open_time"]."</br>";
    }
} else {
    $message=$message. "close".$row_qu["Closing_time"]."</br>";
}
```

**Dynamic query**

```
$sql = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT Rest_Details.Resturant_ID,  Rest_Details.Resturant_name,,Delivery_Pcode.Pcode 
 FROM Rest_Details INNER JOIN Delivery_Pcode
 ON Delivery_Pcode.Restaurant_ID=Rest_Details.Resturant_ID
 WHERE Delivery_Pcode.Pcode LIKE '%" . $pcode . "%'") or die("could not search!");
echo var_dump($sql);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if ($count === 0) {
    $output = '<b>we dont deliver to ' . $pcode . '</b></br>';
} else {
    $i = 1;
}
while ($row_prods = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $rest_id = $row_prods['Resturant_ID'];
    $rest_name = $row_prods['Resturant_name'];

    $output = $output . '<div id="products">' .
            ' <p id="rest_name">' . $rest_name . '</p>' .
            '<p> '.$message.' </p>' .;
    $i++;
}
}
```

Comment: You could just `LEFT JOIN` Opening_hrs in your dynamic query and have the opening hours returned with all the other restaurant info.

Comment: There are several problems with your code. In the `Opening hr query`, you're accessing `$row_qu["Closing_time"]` in the `else` clause when `$row_qu` isn't set. The dynamic query has an extra `}` at the end.

Comment: I don't understand how these are supposed to work together. The opening hours query is just for a single restaurant, but the dynamic query is for all restaurants. Why are you putting the same restaurant's opening hours in the results for all restaurants?

Comment: Since you're using `mysqli`, you should use prepared queries instead of substituting variables directly into the query.

Comment: @Barmar maybe i didn't explain properly. I apologise the opening hrs query is meant to show the opening and closing hours for each restaurant thats why i want it within the loop. So the loop with output the restaurant name, id and opening hours

Comment: @ccKep because i want the two queries to have different echo. maybe use two different if statements?

Answer (score 1):

You should join the two queries:

```
SELECT
    Rest_Details.Resturant_ID,
    Rest_Details.Resturant_name,
    Delivery_Pcode.Pcode,
    Opening_hrs.Open_time,
    Opening_hrs.Closing_time
FROM Rest_Details
JOIN Deliver_Pcode ON Delivery_Pcode.Restaurant_ID=Rest_Details.Restaurant_ID
LEFT JOIN Opening_hrs ON Opening_Hrs.Restaurant_ID=Rest_Details.Restaurang_ID
    AND Day_of_week = WEEKDAY(NOW()) AND CURTIME() BETWEEN Open_time AND Closing_time
WHERE Delivery_Pcode.Pcode LIKE '%$pcode%'
```

Because it's a `LEFT JOIN`, `Open_time` and `Closing_time` will be filled in if the restaurant is open, otherwise they will be `NULL`. So the PHP that displays the results can check this:

```
while ($row_prods = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $rest_id = $row_prods['Resturant_ID'];
    $rest_name = $row_prods['Resturant_name'];

    $output .= '<div id="products">' .
            ' <p id="rest_name">' . $rest_name . '</p>';
    if ($row_prods['Open_time']) {
        $output .= '<p> open ' . $row_prods['Open_time'] . ' close ' . $row_prods['Close_time'];
    }
    $output .= "</div>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Sorry only just seen this. Thank you. I will try and follow this to solve my problem. But this exactly answer has caused a number of issues i will work through. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a list of all restaurants which will deliver within a certain range of plzs and their opening hours then you could use this query:

```
$sql = '
SELECT
    Rest_Details.Resturant_ID,
    Rest_Details.Resturant_name,
    Delivery_Pcode.Pcode,
    EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM Opening_hrs
        WHERE
            Restaurant_ID=' . $rest_id . ' AND
            Day_of_week = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%w") AND
            CURTIME() BETWEEN Open_time AND Closing_time
    ) as isOpen
FROM Rest_Details INNER JOIN Delivery_Pcode
ON Delivery_Pcode.Restaurant_ID=Rest_Details.Resturant_ID
WHERE Delivery_Pcode.Pcode LIKE "%' . $pcode . '%"
';
```

Mysql `exist()` will return `1` if one or more rows match the the specified query and `0` otherwise. `as isOpen` will make this value accesibble in column with name `isOpen`.

Comment: Please test again. If an error or problem occurs post error message or problem description.